# Put 2 lines on highchart with ajax and dynamic updating

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts, dynamic-data

I'm trying to put a second line on a Highchart using ajax with dynamic (periodic) updating. First line works fine using ajax.  I think the problem is the format of the incoming data, but also how I'm *splitting* the data for each of the lines.

I have control of the format of the ajax data so it be could posted in most any form but it works for the first line.

Here is the ajax data that is received with each request:

```
[Date.parse("2013/02/14 14:29:00 -0000"),  51, 216510]
```

This will create a point for the first line at **51** but not anything for the second line which should be at **216510**.

The following is the javascript I'm using:

```
        var chart; // global



    /**
     * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout to request again
     */
    function requestData() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/htbin/count_since_total', 
            success: function(point) {
                var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 30; // shift if the series is longer than 300 (drop oldest point)

                // add the point
                chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);

                // call it again after one second
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);  
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'time'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis

            title: {text: 'count'},
            opposite: false

        }, { // Secondary yAxis

            title: {text: 'Total'},
            opposite: true
        }],

            series: [{
                yAxis: 0,
                name: 'number',
                data: []
            },{
                yAxis: 1,
                name: 'Total',
                data: []
            }],

        });     
    });
```

EDIT 1:
Not working, no second line with suggested changes.  I'm thinking that incoming data format is incorrect or it needs processing after receiving.  Also how does the data get assigned to the proper line?

```
            series: [{
                yAxis: 0,
                name: 'number',
                data: []
            },{
                yAxis: 1,
                name: 'Total',
                data: []
            }],
```

---------  end EDIT 1  ----------------

Answer (score 0):

In your `success`-action/function, you are only updating `series[0]`.

If you want to add a point to the second line, you'll have to add a point to `series[1]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `for` loop to do the same for each serie.

```
success: function(point) {
    for(var i = 0, length = chart.series.length; i < length; i++) {
        var serie = chart.series[i],

        // shift if the series is longer than 300 (drop oldest point)
        var shift = serie.data.length > 30;

        // add the point
        serie.addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);

    }

    // call it again after one second
    setTimeout(requestData, 1000);  
}
```